# R: caret package: createResample

Tags: r, prediction

*I am a newbie to both R and Data Sciences -- hope this helps set the stage for my Q*.

Why would one want to use **createResample** function in the caret package and not  **createFolds**? Wouldn't having repeated selections distort the predictive capabilities of the function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating selections helps removing bias of estimators generated out of the samples. The point to note however is, these selections are not repeated in ordered. Randomizing the selection and hence the sample population and generating estimators aims to remove possible training set overfitting.